# Ignoring Warning about detached ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, warnings

I am loading a ViewController from a Storyboard like this:

```
SSContentViewController* contentViewController =
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil]
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsViewController"];
```

and add it to my ViewController Array:

```
[self.viewControllers addObject:contentViewController];
```

inside the SettingsViewController I have a segue with presents a modal view controller. If I perform this segue I get a "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"-Warning in the console output.

But there is nothing wrong with it. Everything is working as expected. Is it safe to ignore this warning?

EDIT:

The problem is that the ViewController on which I perform the segue is added to my RootViewController with:

```
[rootVC.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

So I know that it is detached. But even with that warning things are working as they should and do not produce visual errors, etc...

Comment: But it hasn't solved the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

you should actually use presentViewcontroller and dismissviewcontroller to avoid this.

Instead of adding use:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:contentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And from model view use below to dismiss:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Edit 01:
for frame rate drop try below:

```
 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:^{

        [self performSelector:@selector(reinit) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

    }];
```

Comment: Updated Please try now.

Comment: Sure I understand! And, yes that works. But it gets me to another problem. After the ViewController is being dismissed the framerate drops from 60 FPS to about 40 FPS and scrolling and everything else isn't smooth anymore. If I do it the old way I still get that warning but it does not affect the rendering performance. I am working with UIVisualEffectView in the Background which seems to be the problem of the FPS drop - which does not occur when presenting the ViewController on a detached view controller.

Comment: Generally this should not happen due to presentViewController. Can you verify that you did not left any of your rendering block still open. And Btw do you use segue ? In that case try using (performSegueWithIdentifier)

Comment: Using (performSegueWithIdentifier) leads to the same problems. On the RootViewController there is no warning but it drops the FPS a lot. On the detached ViewController I get that warning but the FPS is unaffected after (dismissViewControllerAnimated)

Comment: Hmmm so this drop in frame rate is continuous or just at the time of dismissing viewcontroller? If this is the case you should try the edit in my answer.

Comment: It it continuous and starts after (dismissViewControllerAnimated) is being called.

Comment: Not sure. Let me make a make some sample code and verify the issue.